# How to get the content of a cell in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to be able to take out one value in the table and reference it somewhere else in my code but I can only get the print statement to print a column.

```
Animals.csv {
Animal, Name, Age
Dog, Albert, 2
Cat, John, 8
Monkey, Ege, 3
}
```

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("Animals.csv")

print(data["Monkey"]["Name"])
```

and it should print out `Ege` (the content of cell, instead of a full column, with index)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about :

```py
print(data["Monkey"]["Name"].values[0])
```

As previously, you extract the row/column you want, based on the row's index and column name. Then `.values` turn the result dataframe into a numpy arrays of values. Finally, just retrieve the first (and only) element

You might also be able to use :

```py
print(data["Monkey"].iloc[0]["Name"])
```

Comment: Thank you it works!

Comment: You are welcome ! Do not hesitate to validate the answer, it helps other users find answer to a similar question as yours :)

Answer (score 1):

First you filter the dataframe by the condition that Animal is a Monkey.  This will return row 2. Then you index that row by Name:

```
data = pd.read_csv("Animals.csv")
result = data[data['Animal'] == 'Monkey']['Name']

print(result)
#2    Ege
```

Comment: Thank you this works as well!

Comment: You are welcome.  Don't forget to accept the answer.